# Extending XBRL Presentation Networks

Tags: xbrl

I understand XBRL presentation networks very well, and I also understand the mechanisms of prohibiting and overriding relationships, but the way to extend a presentation network with a new, custom concept eludes me.

A presentation network defines a hierarchy of locators, where each locator points to a concept. This makes it possible for the same concept to appear multiple times inside the same network (for example the Equity concept in the Changes of Equity statement, IFRS taxonomy).

The question is: How can an extension taxonomy attach a new arc to a particular locator in the base taxonomy? When an extension taxonomy defines a new arc, that new arc points to two new locators in the same extension taxonomy and will therefore not integrate with the network that is defined by the base taxonomy.

Answer (score 1):

The locators are "proxies" to concepts, and a syntactic detail. From a logical perspective, a presentation network is a DAG of report elements (="concepts" in specese). When prohibiting and overriding, what matters in the resolution of the DTS is the concepts, not the locators.

In [specese](http://www.xbrl.org/Specification/XBRL-2.1/REC-2003-12-31/XBRL-2.1-REC-2003-12-31+corrected-errata-2013-02-20.html#_3.5.3.9.7.4) wording, two relationships are equivalent if their (non-exempt) attributes match, and the XML fragments on the from and to sides are identical. The XML fragments of the from and to sides, in a presentation network, are [the concepts, not the locators](http://www.xbrl.org/Specification/XBRL-2.1/REC-2003-12-31/XBRL-2.1-REC-2003-12-31+corrected-errata-2013-02-20.html#_3.5.3.9).

An extension taxonomy will thus have its own locators, but pointing to the same concepts if it wants to reuse them.

Comment: If an extension taxonomy defines an arc from a concept of the base taxonomy to a new custom concept, what determines to which _location_ (or instance) of the concept in the DAG the new arc attaches, given that the same concept can appear in the same network in multiple locations?

Comment: This is a good question. I look at it mathematically: the DAG is made of nodes (concepts) and arcs. Each concept corresponds to one, and only one node in the DAG. There is thus no ambiguity regarding its location. A concept may "seem" to appear at multiple locations if the DAG is "flattened" to a tree by duplicating all undirected cycles, as is commonly done in software, but it really appears at only one location in the DAG. Attaching an arc from such a "sink" concept thus should add the arc everywhere in the "flattened" tree.

Comment: In practice, however, the primary use case for a concept appearing "multiple times" in a presentation network is for roll-forward patterns, with an instant (concrete) concept appearing with a start date and an end date, and duration concepts in the middle of them containing the change in value. These (concrete) concepts are typically leaves, while the non-leaves are typically abstracts. See for example in EDGAR the statements of cash flow (e.g., Apple, Q2 2018), or statements of change in equity when available.

Comment: The short answer is "nothing"; it appears as a child of all occurrences of the concept to which it is attached.  A practical consequence of how this works is that a single concept cannot appear with different children within the same base set.  For this reason it is common, as Ghislain says, for all non-leaf nodes to be abstract elements.  It's easy to introduce additional abstracts to facilitate different child lists, but you don't want to duplicate reporting concepts.

Comment: Thank you both for your excellent and precise answers. They clarified the issue a lot for me.